# WebSocket: sending data server to client not working

Tags: php, websocket

I made a simple php code to test WebSocket, the client connects without problems, could receive data without probemas, but I can not send data from server to client, please correct my code to work, thanks

server.php

```
$in = '';
$content = '';
$connected = 0;
while($in != "quit"){

    if(!$connected){
        $in=trim(fgets(STDIN));
        $pos = strpos($in, 'Sec-WebSocket-Key:');
        if($pos !== false){
            $key = str_replace('Sec-WebSocket-Key: ','',$in);
            $magic = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
            $resp = shell_exec("echo -n $key$magic | openssl sha1 -binary | base64");
        }
        if($in == ""){
            $head = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
            $head.= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
            $head.= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
            $head.= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $resp\r\n";
            $head.= "\r\n";
            echo $head;
            $connected = 1;
        }
    }else{
        sleep(3);

        $hex = "810461626364"; //abcd
        $byte = str_split($hex, 2);
        $out = '';
        foreach($byte as $b){
            $out.= chr(hexdec($b));
        }
        echo $out;
    }
}
```

type in terminal:

```
ncat -l 12345 -c 'php -q server.php'
```

and connect the client to localhost:12345

Comment: We're not a code-writing service, what do you think is wrong? Are there any errors?

Comment: when the server tries to send the message to the client, the client disconnects without displaying the message.

Comment: You need to encode the proper message header and attach it to the front of your message before sending the message to the client. I don't see any of that in your code. I also don't see where messages sent from clients are unmasked; all I see is handshake negotiation.

Comment: the code $hex = "810461626364"; should send the message "abcd" to client with echo, 81 = text, 04 = length and no mask, 61 = a, 62 = b, 63 = c, 64 = d, but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved, it was not working because it had two line breaks after the response header, I changed this

```
$head.= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $resp\r\n";
$head.= "\r\n";
echo $head;
```

for this

```
$head.= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $resp\r\n";
echo $head;
```

and it worked.